# Discovering people connected on hub network

Tags: networking

Sorry, I'm really newbie on ubuntu matters. Is there a way of discovering everyone connected on a hub with wireless network (IP and name)?

Comment: The question seems unrelated to Ubuntu, and probably belongs on a networking forum.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought there would be a command to run where I can see who is connected to that lan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nmap to scan the range of ip addresses in your subnet. For example,

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254
```

Nmap doesn't come installed on Ubuntu by default. If you don't have it, get it:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```